# how to get class name from jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway to get the name of a class when it is unknown to jquery

```
<input type="checkbox" id="if you tick me" class="tickme" onClick="myfunction(this)">
<input type="checkbox" id="you tick me also" class="tickme">

function myfunction(x) {
                $('."unknown class name goes here"').prop('checked', 'true')
}
```

therefore when the first one is checked the second one is two but you dont know either of the class names but the class names are the same and you have to use a class and not and id.

Comment: You have to use a selector. So maybe `$(':checkbox')`? But just out of curiosity, why don't you know the classname?

Comment: Just use any of the many ways jQuery allows you to select the element. You're not limited to only classes and IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
function handleClick(x) {
    $("." + $(x).attr("class")).prop('checked', true)
}
```

this will get the class name from the this keyword

Comment: perfect thats just what i needed thank you so so much.

Comment: What happens if the element has more than one class?